# How to delete all text between <> in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a GoogleSheets document with rows filled with example:

```
<a href="/retailer/150319" class="directory-link">2-Cycle GmbH</a>          
            
<a href="/retailer/164964" class="directory-link">2-Rad-Sport Wehrle</a>
```

How do I quickly delete everything between the < > so only the name remains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A2; "<\/\w+>|<\w+.*?>"; )))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A2; "</?\S+[^<>]*>"; )))
```

Comment: Awesome that works but I am INCREDIBLY new to GoogleSheets.  How do I edit it to make it apply to the entire sheet?  Can you tell me the variable to edit so I can make it apply to the entire list? It's over 1000 lines long

Comment: @user20267765 if your dataset is in A column you can change `A1:A2` to `A1:A`